# Understanding block reward calculation

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, block-reward, median-blocksize

I've read [this explanation](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1074/1061) of how block rewards are calculated. But I fail to apply it in practice. Let's take [block #1233057](http://chainradar.com/xmr/block/1233057) as an example:

[image: Block #1233057]

The base reward is 8.8005 (which matches the result of the formula given in the explanation).

The block size is less that the effective median size of 60kB, so the base reward should be paid in full.

There is a transaction fee of 0.036.

So I would expect the actual reward to be 8.8005 + 0.036 = 8.8365, but it shows as 8.9017.

**How is the final reward of 8.9017 calculated for that block?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chainradar doesn't show RingCT transaction fees (they are explicitly defined rather than sum(inputs) - sum(outputs), and they clearly haven't added support for that). Try http://moneroblocks.info/search/1233057