# Can Monero miners be picky about adding transactions to blocks

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, mining, privacy, transaction-fees

With Bitcoin, miners are picky about which transactions to add to blocks due to the limited block size, opting for transactions with higher fees (larger transactions). This means micro/nano payments take a long time (if at all) to process on the bitcoin blockchain.

Can this happen on Monero ? Is there anything there to disincentivize mining nano/micro payments? I’m aware that the block size grows and that miners only know the range of the transaction amount but is this enough when monero scales up like bitcoin has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially.

Miners can't know *who* send *how much* to *who*. What miners do know is the fee associated to the transaction. One way miners can "select" transactions would be to prioritise higher fees, which is actually how a lot of cryptocurrencies work.

What miners can't do is prioritise transactions, on their own, to/from addresses. They would only be able to do so if the transaction maker gave them the tx-id.

> With Bitcoin, miners are picky about which transactions to add to blocks due to the limited block size

This won't happen on the long-term with Monero due to the *Dynamic Block Size* which specifically prevents a Bitcoin situation from occurring.

Comment: The algorithm on which block size increase is based is designed to maintain a stable growth of around 0.6% in size. There’s a reward penalty for increasing block size too much. This means that miners are still going to try pack the high fee transactions into smaller blocks (relatively smaller) because it equates to a greater reward. If monero gets the kind of transaction traffic bitcoin has than I don’t see how the block size increase would keep up fast enough such that miners don’t get picky about which transactions to pack. Correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: Partially correct. It isn't based on stable growth as [explained here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1068/4798). But the details don't matter to this question. The point is that it wouldn't happen on the long-term as I stated. There may be a period when this occurs but eventually the demand/offer of block size will balance again. Now this can be a matter of days like it can be a matter of month depending on the spike in traffic.

Comment: According to this : https://github.com/JollyMort/monero-research/blob/master/Monero%20Dynamic%20Block%20Size%20and%20Dynamic%20Minimum%20Fee/Monero%20Dynamic%20Block%20Size%20and%20Dynamic%20Minimum%20Fee%20-%20DRAFT.md  It is based on steady block growth (based on the last 100 blocks). Now if transaction rates spike while the block size expansion remains steady, then theoretically you would get fee picky miners excluding smaller transactions. And so back to my question: apart from block size growth then what further mechanism of prevention from such pickiness does Monero have?

Comment: The pickiness is by design.  If blocks are full, there will be a backlog of `unimportant` and `normal` priority transactions. If senders don't mind waiting, then they won't send with a higher fee.  If they send with a higher fee, miners will choose those transactions, the blocksize grows faster, and the people who sent with lower priority fees will have their transactions included in blocks even sooner.

Comment: @Zigglzworth None. Bitcoin has pickiness on fees, amounts, outgoing and incoming transactions. Monero's privacy prevents these three last ones from happening.

Comment: @scoobybejesus - i guess it comes down to the long term economic vision of Monero. If the architects don’t see a currency which foster smaller things such as buying some mil from the local store then the pickiness is by design sure. If on the other hand such transactions become integral to the long term adoption of monero than perhaps the issue needs to be addressed more directly

Comment: Well, long-term is when things get interesting.  The fees, relative to one another, will remain the same.  But if the network has enough transactions to maintain a blocksize bigger than the minimum, then fees will decrease.  The same amount of fees will be associated with each block, roughly.  So a double of the block size means everyone only has to pay half the default fee.  If the block size doubles again, the fee will again be half of that.  So with increased network usage, all users benefit from a reduction in their fees.